# Extraction of all space free strings

Tags: string, powershell, extract

The trial script shown below aims at extracting the space free strings from a text file `F` and passing them in the order found to a result file `Fr` where they are set one per line. Overall it works fine, except on the ends of lines where there might be a skipped line in the result file, except that I don't know if it is a script that stops properly, and except that, worst of all, it takes for ever to do its job.

```
$fic= "<F>"
$ficr="<Fr>"
$fics="<Fs>"
$cF=(gc $fic -encoding utf8)
clc $fics;clc $ficr
$Lfic=(gc $fic).length;
$MPfic=$Lfic-1;$Pfic=0..$MPfic
foreach($x in $Pfic){$llge=((gc $fic)[$x]).length;$mplge=$llge-1;$plge=0..$mplge;foreach($y in $plge)
                       {if($cF[$x][$y] -ne " "){$cF[$x][$y] >> $fics} 
                                               else {if($cF[$x][$y+1] -ne " ")
                                                       {(-join (gc $fics)) >> $ficr;clc $fics}else{while($cF[$x][$y+1] -eq " "){$y=$y+1}}
                                                    }
                       }
                     }
```

1/ Will someone know what to do to perfect that script? (I'd like to preserve it as an illustration of the unrealistic coding possibilities that one might encounter.)

2/ Could someone suggest a more efficient code for the job to be done?

---

*Example of what input and output look like*

For instance, if in file `F` the text is as follows (spaces have been replaced with vertical bars but in normal text this is meaningless, the bars being just as any other characters; here they are meant to show precicely where and how spaces can occur;  the line indications (line x) do not belong to the texts, which starts always at the beginning of the line (no starting white spaces). "Line 2" in the input is an empty line.),

```
line 1   %|10|prog|axil,|(les|prog|activés)  
line 2     
line 3   %|début%||||||||||||||||Ce|qu'il|faut:|<<~ZZZ_if_livre_op_prog_PX.txt~>>
line 4   %|à|partir|du|mot|<<~index~>>
```

what should be in file `Fr` is this:

```
line 1  %
line 2  10
line 3  prog
line 4  axil,
line 5  (les
line 6  prog
line 7  activés)
line 8  %
line 9  début%
line 10 Ce
line 11 qu'il
line 12 faut:
line 13 <<~ZZZ_if_livre_op_prog_LPX.txt~>>
line 14 %
line 15 à
line 16 partir
line 17 du
line 18 mot
line 19 <<~index~>>
```

Comment: You really over complicating things, you might simply do this with the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) cmdlet and a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression): `Get-Content $fic |  Select-String '^[^ ]+$' | Set-Content $ficr`

Comment: @iRon Thank you very much, valuable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to split on all the whitespace?

```
-split (get-content spaces.txt)
```

To get rid of blank lines, -raw reads the whole file as one string, instead of a string for each line.

```
-split (get-content -raw spaces.txt)
```

Comment: @LPH It's an operator, not a parameter - that whole statement is valid by itself

Comment: Do you mean that afer plugging the path of the file in the place of "spaces.txt" the execution of that in the ISE gives the result on the screen? Yes, perfect; thank you very much! Wonderful speed!

Comment: If you put the -split operator on the left side, it splits on variable white space.

Comment: @js2010 I thought I'd better tell you that with this operator empty lines are not skipped, they are rendered by empty lines in the output; however that is no problem in my script, I can take care of that.

Comment: `get-content -raw` would take care of that.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your current script seems overly complicated. You could simplify it as (pseudocode):

```
foreach $line in F {
    if $line has a space {
        Write $line to Fs
    }
    else {
        Write $line to Fr
    }
}
```

In PowerShell that might look like:

```
# read all lines from file
$lines = Get-Content $fic -Encoding utf8

# split into two groups - those that contain whitespace and those that don't
$withSpace,$withoutSpace = $lines.Where({$_ -match '\s'}, 'Split')

# write the lines with whitespace to $fics
$withSpace |Set-Content $fics

# write the lines without whitespace to $ficr
$withoutSpace |Set-Content $ficr
```

Comment: Probably, I didn't phrase the problem right. What I called "space free strings" are those elements put between spaces **in** the lines, as in the following (each space is marked as **SPACE**), not lines:  ldijfhd**SPACE**:§!fokjdhjhuy**SPACE**52fo5rd6**SPACE**yp^$rà0@. Therefore, the code you propose, which is instructive to me anyway, does not do what is needed.

Comment: @LPH could you update your post with an example of what the input looks like, and what you expect the output to look like? It's not very clear right now

Comment: Yes, I'll do that.

Comment: I just made the addition you asked for.

Comment: @LPH, ahh, so you basically only want the _non-empty_ fields?

Comment: I don't know this name but I presume you have no doubt as to what  I meant and therefore that the name corresponds to what I want.

Comment: @LPH That makes sense now :D